# I need to export data for x and y from an CSV file

Tags: python, csv

The data has negative and non integer values. e.g. `... -0.00046`. I have used a code to open the file and read the x and y data but the output I get is only the first non zero digit of the value.

This is my code:

```
import csv

x = []
y = []
f = open("sample.csv")

for row in f:
    x.append(row[1])
    for col in f:
       y.append(col[1])
print(y)
```

output

```
['4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2',
```

Real data from file

```
-0.00000046,-0.00000045....and so on.
```

Comment: I need it to read the values as it is and use them for a contour plot.

Comment: Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: OpenCSV is a CSV parser for Java. What does it have to do with Python?

Comment: You have `import csv`, why aren't you using it?

Comment: Also, seeing the `sample.csv` would help :)

Comment: After appending the first row (i.e. line) to `x`, the second *character* all the remaining line in the entire file will be appended to `y` because of the nested `for col in f:` loop. Your code is not using the `csv` module at all.

Comment: Thank you guys for the useful comments. I realized I was not using the csv module at all. I tried the numpy module with no.loadtext and that worked. Also, the code given below by Tien works as well.

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
import numpy as np
x = []
y = []
f = np.loadtxt(open("sample.csv", "rb"), delimiter=",", skiprows=1)
for col in f:
    y.append(col[0])
print(y)
```